# How do I checkout existing remote branch with git worktree - Not in local refs

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have a branch feature/issue/xyz on github and when I try to checkout via git-worktee it keeps telling me does not exist

```
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

I know it exists , verified bot on github & in a non worktree clone locally
I have tried :
`git worktree add --track -b feature/issue/xyz feature/issue/xyz origin/feature/issue/xyz`

`git worktree add --track -b feature/issue/xyz feature/issue/xyz origin/feature/issue/xyz`

and
`git worktree add --track -b feature/issue/xyz feature/issue/xyz refs/heads/feature/issue/xyz`

I have tried git fetching but all I see is

```
 * branch              HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and still get the same result after I try to add again

Comment: You have a *single-branch clone*. You need to "undo" its single-branch-ness. (It's not clear to me how you're supposed to know that you have this, other than if you remember running `git clone --single-branch` or `git clone --depth` whenever you ran `git clone` originally. But that's the problem.)

Comment: unless I am misunderstanding you, this is not a single branch clone, its a bare clone to work with git worktree `git clone --bare ...`

Comment: It may or may not be bare, but it's apparently *also* a single-branch clone, based on the `git fetch` result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by:

`git fetch origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'`

and then simply add  `git worktree add feature/issue/xyz feature/issue/xyz` and this pulled the correct branch

Comment: This "works", but it's not the same as actually branching from `origin/feature/issue/xyz` directly - fetching all remote branches first is slow and needs to be re-run every time you want to reference the remote's state. By contrast branching from `origin/...` is automatically in-sync with the commits on the remote without needing to fetch all branches.